# Copy data from one table to other using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public int insert() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("INSERT INTO EmployeeGroup SELECT * FROM Employee");
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(buf.toString());
    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Getting error   "INSERT INTO EmployeeGroup SELECT * FROM Employee"

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found 'SELECT' near line 1, column 36 [INSERT INTO EmployeeGroup SELECT * FROM Employee]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
... 30 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Use `createNativeQuery` to make it work and also give Table names instead of entity names (Replace EmployeeGroup and Employee with actual table name instead of Entity names).

Comment: thank you. Really hoping to use entity names. EmployeeGroup  table (oracle) is on a different server than Employee (sql server). I have defined two data sources in my application.   <bean id="sounce1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  <bean id="sounce2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">. Not sure how add persistenceUnitName to a query INSERT INTO EmployeeGroup SELECT * FROM Employee